# User defined variables using SET is not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2

I am using `node 5.0.0` along with the node module `mysql2 - 1.0.0-rc.11`. It is working perfectly fine except when I try to use the [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

Example :

```
SET @user := 123456;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = @user;
```

The above simple query is throwing syntax error at my end. I am sure that, the syntax is a valid one. So I am wondering what may be the cause for this issue?

Doesn't the node module `mysql2 - 1.0.0-rc.11` have support for SET yet? I have scanned the [[document1](https://libraries.io/npm/mysql2/1.0.0-rc.11), [document2]](https://libraries.io/npm/mysql2/1.0.0-rc.11) thoroughly, I couldn't able to find the syntax support list. Can anyone help me to understand what's going wrong with this?

Comment: Are you trying to do both in the same `query()` or separately?

Comment: if you want to query both at the same time (which is not recommended) you need to set `multipleStatements` flag in your connection parameters - see https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Andrey Sidorov's comment, you will need to have `multipleStatements: true` in the options object you pass to createConnection(), createPool(), etc. This is `false` by default for security reasons, so I don't recommend using it in production code.

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries